# jQuery removing part of string after "#" and removing "# "too

Tags: javascript, string

I wonder how can i remove all string part after "#".
For example if i have `example.com/hello#item1` how can i remove all characteres after `#` and `#` character too?

Comment: you got 3 completely different ways to do it... take your pick

Comment: ...and none of them involve jQuery, of course.

Comment: Good to know. Just involve JavaScript?

Comment: @Cris, indeed. You don't need jQuery to manipulate strings unless you want to [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) them, and even that can be done with a simple regex too.

Comment: Regex are the same in most of languages?

Comment: @Cris regex is not the same in all languages, but javascript regex is standard and will work in all browsers that support javascript.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
var string = "example.com/hello#item1".split('#')[0];
```

simple as that

Comment: Note, that string will be undefined, when # is not found. You might think, that it should return the whole string in that case instead.

Comment: it will always return whole string.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use split.

```
var oldString ='somestring#removethis';
var newString = oldString.split('#', 1)[0];
alert(newString);
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/DGFuf/1/

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "example.com/hello#item1";
str = str.replace(/#.*$/,'');
```

Comment: maybe i do somethin wrong but this code cuts all except domain.

Comment: It should be if You saying that. My mistake somewhere for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = "example.com/hello#item1";

    var newStr = str.substring(0, (str.length - str.indexOf("#")));
```

Comment: is this the opposite of code golf? what would that be called..? code flog?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
var str = "example.com/hello#item1".split('#')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
location.href.replace(location.hash,"")
```

that'll do it

#### edit

oops... string... hm... well this is how you remove it from the url XDDD