# removing http:// or http:// and www

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a url cleaner.

I am looking to get a list of urls and remove all `https://`, `http://`, `www.`, etc. from the beginning as well as all text after the trailing `/`.

I have tried the following regex `url.replace(/^https?\:\/\/www\./i, "").split('/')[0];`

This works to a certain extent and outputs the following

```
"www.net-temps.com"
"www.toplanguagejobs.com"
"http:"
"peopleready.com"
"nationjob.com"
"http:"
"bluesteps.com"
"https:"
"theguardian.com"
"reddit.com"
"youtube.com"
"https:"
"pgatour.com"
"cultofmac.com"
```

from the following list:

```
'www.net-temps.com',
'www.toplanguagejobs.com',
'http://nychires.com/',
'http://www.peopleready.com/',
'https://www.nationjob.com/',
'http://nationaljobsonline.com/',
'https://www.bluesteps.com/',
'https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-we-got-our-2-year-old-open-source-project-to-trend-on-github-8c25b0a6dfe9#.nl4985bjz',
'https://www.theguardian.com/uk/business',
'https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/5qzkz4/my_captain_friend_sent_me_this_photo_saudi_prince/',
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bua8k_CcnuI',
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000995/jquery-removing-part-of-string-after-and-removing-too/7001040#7001040',
'http://www.pgatour.com/fantasy.html',
'http://www.cultofmac.com/464645/apple-spaceship-campus-flyover/'
```

If I remove the `/www\.` from the regex this works well and removes all `https:` etc., but I'd also like to remove the `www.` if it's there regardless of `https:`

This is what i have coded so far

https://jsfiddle.net/xba5x9ro/1/

In the future once this is sorted. I would like to take a list of urls from a text area run `makeDomainBeautiful` and output to another textarea but thought I'd get this working first.

Comment: To clarify, given an url of the form: `protocol://subdomain.domain.tld/path` you want to retrieve only the `domain.tld` part?

Comment: Why is `'jQuery removing part of string after "#" and removing "# "too'` in URL list? What is expected result?

Comment: I'm sure that the answer is probably in one of the 6,041 results of questions already asked on this topic;  I just haven't read many of them to find the best result.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+http%3A%2F%2F+www.

Comment: The expected result should just leave domain.com for example. So it would strip all http://www. and any trailing string after .com/......

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i` where both `https://` and `www.` should be optional (`?`) and non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`).

```js
var url = prompt("url: ");

url = url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i, "").split('/')[0];

alert("url: " + url);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will take care of `http`, `https` and `www`

```
url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i, "").split('/')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = prompt("url: ");

url = url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i, "").split('/')[0];

alert("url: " + url);
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on ibrahim mahrir answer, if you just want to trim the http or https and www from the start of the URL, but keep the rest. Mocked it up in codepen to test if it works. Seems to work nicely.
https://codepen.io/pureth/pen/LQOaPz

```js
var regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i;
var urlList = [
  "www.net-temps.com",
  "www.toplanguagejobs.com",
  "http://nychires.com/",
  "http://www.peopleready.com/",
  "https://www.nationjob.com/",
  "http://nationaljobsonline.com/",
  "https://www.bluesteps.com/",
  "https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-we-got-our-2-year-old-open-source-project-to-trend-on-github-8c25b0a6dfe9#.nl4985bjz",
  "https://www.theguardian.com/uk/business",
  "https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/5qzkz4/my_captain_friend_sent_me_this_photo_saudi_prince/",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bua8k_CcnuI",
  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000995/jquery-removing-part-of-string-after-and-removing-too/7001040#7001040",
  "http://www.pgatour.com/fantasy.html",
  "http://www.cultofmac.com/464645/apple-spaceship-campus-flyover/"
];

urlList.forEach(function(url) {
  let $originalEl = $("<div class='url'>" + url + "</div>"),
    cleanUrl = url.replace(regex, ""),
    $cleanEl = $("<div class='url'>" + cleanUrl + "</div>");
  $(".original").append($originalEl);
  $(".clean").append($cleanEl);
});
```

```css
.original, .clean {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 350px;
  float: left;
}
.title {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.url {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="original">
  <div class="title"><b>original</b></div>
</div>
<div class="clean">
  <div class="title"><b>clean</b></div>
</div>
```