# passing url to dns.lookup()

Tags: node.js, dns

I'm getting error on dns.lookup() for url's. Any help?? Say for example
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942690/removing-http-or-http-and-www/41942787`

I've removed the https:// and still it's not working.

```
var dns = require('dns');
var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942690/removing-http-or-http-and-www/41942787";
dns.lookup(url,(error,address,family)=>{
  console.log(error,address,family)
})
```

Comment: Maybe `dns.lookup()` expects just the hostname and not a whole URL?

Comment: But I need to know if the url is valid or not

Comment: If your problem is knowing if a URL is valid you should ask that (and define what _valid_ means). Right now, even if you get a good answer for this question it won't solve your real problem, cause DNS lookup doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

[dns.lookup(hostname[, options], callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback)

Parse the URL and retrieve hostname, pass it to `dns.lookup()` function.

```
const dns = require('dns');
const url = require('url'); 
const lookupUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942690/removing-http-or-http-and-www/41942787";

const parsedLookupUrl = url.parse(lookupUrl);

console.log(parsedLookupUrl);
```

> Url auth: null hash: null host: "stackoverflow.com" hostname:
>   "stackoverflow.com" href:
>   "[removing http:// or http:// and www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942690/removing-http-or-http-and-www/41942787)"
>   path: "/questions/41942690/removing-http-or-http-and-www/41942787"
>   pathname: "/questions/41942690/removing-http-or-http-and-www/41942787"
>   port: null protocol: "https:" query: null search: null slashes: true
>   Url Prototype

```
dns.lookup(parsedLookupUrl.hostname,(error,address,family)=>{
  console.log(error,address,family)
});
```